# Get public key into PubKeyHash and use it in mustBeSignedBy

Tags: plutus, statemachines

A user provides me with his wallet pub key as BultinByteString (or Haskell string, fine either way). From that, I need to get the PubKeyHash, but I am not sure how to hash it or if I need to hash it at all.

Then, I need to use it in the PubKeyHash in Ledger.Constraints.MustBeSignedBy in my state machine. Kinda like that:

```
Constraints.mustBeSignedBy "35dedd2982a03cf39e7dce03c839994ffdec2ec6b04f1cf2d40e61a3"
```

or

```
Constraints.mustBeSignedBy PubKeyHash { getPubKeyHash = "35dedd2982a03cf39e7dce03c839994ffdec2ec6b04f1cf2d40e61a3" }
```

The problem is when I put some PubKeyHash in the constraint (like above), the compiler spits out 5000 long error starting with:

```
GHC Core to PLC plugin: E042:Error: Unsupported feature: Use of fromString on type other than builtin strings or bytestrings: Plutus.V1.Ledger.Crypto.PubKeyHash
Context: Compiling expr: Data.String.fromString
                           @ Plutus.V1.Ledger.Crypto.PubKeyHash
                           Plutus.V1.Ledger.Crypto.$fIsStringPubKeyHash
                           (GHC.CString.unpackCString#
                              "a2c20c77887ace1cd986193e4e75babd8993cfd56995cd5cfce609c2"#)
```

Can the string be translated into the PubKeyHash? Can it be somehow fixed? Is it me, or is it a Plutus bug?

*Edit:*

Tried new code:

```
Constraints.mustBeSignedBy $ pubKeyHash (PubKey {
                            getPubKey = LedgerBytes { 
                                    getLedgerBytes = "35dedd2982a03cf39e7dce03c839994ffdec2ec6b04f1cf2d40e61a3" 
                                }
                        })
```

Got new error:

```
 GHC Core to PLC plugin: E042:Error: Unsupported feature: Type constructor: GHC.Prim.Char#
Context: Compiling type: GHC.Prim.Char#
Context: Compiling data constructor type: GHC.Types.C#
Context: Compiling type: GHC.Types.Char
Context: Compiling type: GHC.Base.String
Context: Compiling type: GHC.Base.String
                         -> Plutus.V1.Ledger.Bytes.LedgerBytes
Context: Compiling definition of: Plutus.V1.Ledger.Bytes.$fIsStringLedgerBytes_$cfromString
Context: Compiling expr: Plutus.V1.Ledger.Bytes.$fIsStringLedgerBytes_$cfromString
Context: Compiling expr: Plutus.V1.Ledger.Bytes.$fIsStringLedgerBytes_$cfromString
...
```

Comment: Did you add OverloadedStrings pragma?

Comment: Yes, I do have that pragma at the beginning of my file. No other issues with strings occurred in my state machine contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with Plutus core. Even though **PubKeyHash** is part of **IsString** type class, we can't use OverloadedStrings mechanism in on-chain code for certain types. Basically, the problem is this:

> Unfortunately, due to the technical reasons plutus plugin doesn't
> support OverloadedStrings with newtypes.

Please, check this issue.

https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues/4404

Same thing apply for `PubKeyHash` and `LedgerBytes`.

A solution might be to have a parameterized validator script with `PubKeyHash`. This way, you can build `PubkeyHash` offchain using **OverloadedStrings** and pass it to the validator.

Comment: Thank you! Parameterized validator script with PubKeyHash works like a charm. Indeed a fascinating issue.

Comment: @MartinDrozdík You’re welcome. glad to help!